# Changing the numeration of sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I need to change the way the command `\section` enumerates the sections: I'd like my second section to be section number 4. (I don't want any section number 2 or three in my article).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Put `\setcounter{section}{3}` just before the second `\section`. And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**

Put `\setcounter{section}{3}` just before the second `\section`.

---

**Long answer**

The numbering of sectioning commands is governed by counters that have the same name as the command, e.g. for the `\section` command we have the counter `section`, for the `\subsection` command we have the counter `subsection`, and so on.

Each time a sectioning command is issued, the corresponding counter is incremented by one.

If you want to change this behavior manually, you have a few possibilities:

1. `\setcounter{counter}{value}`

   Issuing this command you can set the value of `counter` to the specified `value`, e.g. `\setcounter{section}{3}` assigns the value 3 to the counter `section`.
2. `\addtocounter{counter}{value}`

   Issuing this command you can increment the value of `counter` by the specified `value`, e.g. `\addtocounter{section}{2}` increments the counter `section` by a value of 2.
3. `\stepcounter{counter}`

   The same as above but the increment is fixed at 1.
4. `\refstepcounter{counter}`

   The same as above but useful when you're using a label/ref system for the counter.